# Ubuntu 20.04 cloud-init won't configure network

Tags: 20.04, kvm-virtualization, cloud, cloud-init

The issue I have is the exact same as documented by someone on 18.04 years ago on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368104/cloud-init-ignoring-static-ip-network-configuration) but the solution there doesn't work.  My steps to reproduce the problem are as follows:

I start with an image created like this:

```
# cloud-localds -vv --network-config=gluster1net.yaml  vvv.img vvv.yaml 
# qemu-img create -f qcow2 -b focal-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img vvv.qcow2 100G
# virsh create vvv.xml --console
```

The image `vvv.img` is mounted as `/dev/sr0` inside the VM. The image contains what you would expect, as follows:

```
# ls -l test
total 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33 Apr 27 21:39 meta-data
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 321 Apr 27 21:39 network-config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 707 Apr 27 21:39 user-data
# cat test/network-config 
#cloud-config

network:
  version: 2
  ethernets: 
    ens3:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [ "2001:000:1:841:1:0:30:100/64" ]
      gateway6: 2001:470:1:841::1
      nameservers:
        search: [ zzz.com ]
        addresses: [ "2001:4860:4860::8888", "2001:4860:4860::8844" ]
# cat test/meta-data 
{
"instance-id": "iid-local01"
}
```

When the VM boots up, the `user-data` is used properly.  The host name gets set and the user gets set and I can log in.  The `network-config` is ignored, and I end up with a default `netplan` configuration file.  If I manually copy the above yaml file over the one in `/etc/netplan` and do `netplan apply` then I get the network configuration that is needed.  But that is a manual process that cloud-init is supposed to do instead.

I can't find any solution in the cloud-init documentation.  Does anyone here know what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `network` top-level key is optional and gets removed internally by cloud-init. Unfortunately, a bug exists where it isn't removed correctly: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/1906187

Remove the `#cloud-config` header and the `network` key in your `test/network-config` file:

```yaml
version: 2
ethernets:
  ens3:
    dhcp4: false
    dhcp6: false
    addresses: [ "2001:000:1:841:1:0:30:100/64" ]
    gateway6: 2001:470:1:841::1
    nameservers:
      search: [ zzz.com ]
      addresses: [ "2001:4860:4860::8888", "2001:4860:4860::8844" ]
```

Comment: This turns out to do it.   The documentation https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config-format-v2.html is misleading in light of the bug.   I hope this posting helps someone else.